# what type of service architecture is this?

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight-5.0

I am new to silverlight and I have a general question. I created a new silverlight project and added a "silverlight enabled wcf service" to it. I created the service proxy in the silverlight project and I am able to hit the .svc file with no errors.

My question is, what kind of service architecture is this?? Its not showing up in IIS so its not hosted in IIS and its not a self hosted windows based service. Hows does this work?

Are there limitations to this compared to like a "self hosted wcf service" or an "IIS hosted wcf service"?

Thanks in advance!

Below is my endpoint configuration for the service:

```
<endpoint address="https://localhost/SilverBadger.Web/Services/DataAccessService.svc"
                      binding="customBinding" 
                      bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding_DataAccessService"
                      contract="DataAccessService.DataAccessService" 
                      name="CustomBinding_DataAccessService" />
```

Answer (score 2):

That service is hosted in Cassini, Visual Studio's built in development server.  It's just launched along with your project.  It can be hosted in IIS as-is, or modified to run as a self-hosted service.

Comment: Well I published the project and made a new website in IIS for it. The .svc file is part of the website that was published but the service itself is not showing up as a service in IIS. When its published, its still a .svc file. Does that still mean its being hosted through IIS?

Comment: I don't entirely follow you here to be honest, can you clarify what you are asking?

Answer (score 0):

if you are hitting .svc... arent you at IIS... 
.svc extensions means service hosting for IIS

maybe it is localhost

Comment: This is my endpoint address:

<endpoint address="https://localhost/SilverBadger.Web/Services/DataAccessService.svc"
                      binding="customBinding" 
                      bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding_DataAccessService"
                      contract="DataAccessService.DataAccessService" 
                      name="CustomBinding_DataAccessService" />

Im not seeing this service in IIS when I look at the management console. So thats why I was wondering if its actually going through IIS or not??

Comment: did you create that .svc or it is dynamically generated?
but, try to access this endpoint via browser

Comment: .svc extenions was designed for IIS Service Hosting

Comment: Ok, cool. So when the web request comes in through the url, IIS is handling it? Even though the service is not "showing" in IIS and its just a service (svc) file in the web sites directory?

Comment: Yes, because the service contract is inside your .svc like common IIS hosting, try to access this: localhost/SilverBadger.Web/Services/DataAccessService.svc tell me if you are seeing the wsdl